# How to manage assertions in googletest in windows

Tags: c++, windows, googletest

I'm using googletest to check that any derived class implements a function a certain way.

One of the constraints is that it should call `assert(false);` if it can't find the data it should find. If you want to know, this is because the data not being available is a programming error and it should never happen.

Now I want to write a unit test for this interface function, I'm using `TYPED_TEST_P` where the type of class to test is given as a parameter.

**THE GIVEN EXAMPLE IS A SIMPLIFICATION.**

```
TYPED_TEST_P(InterfaceFuntionTests, CheckThatCallAssertsOnNull)
{
   // All m_ prefixed variables are given from the test instantiation.
   // Since we do not know what combination of values is invalid for each
   // class that implements compute.
   EXPECT_DEATH(m_model->compute(m_value1, m_value2, m_value3, m_value4, "Time to die.");
}
```

Everything works fine, but Windows wants to display the `"Abort/Retry/Ignore"`window.

What's the best way to disable this Window? I keep thinking that googletest might have this covered somehow.

```
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT,  _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
// This eats the assertions and the test doesn't work.

_CrtSetReportHook(functionThatReturnsTrue);
// This eats the assertions and the test doesn't work.
```

Note that this issue is specific to **Windows**.

---

I'm half tempted to remove this question, since I found a solution that works.

I'll leave this question here if someone has a better answer.

My solution was to call std::abort(-1); in the report hook function.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, somebody may benefit from it in the future.

Comment: "assert(false)" as programming logic is not great to start with, the point of them being they are compiled out of production builds. I suspect calling `abort` from `abort` is also not defined, but would need to check the standard.

Comment: @FireLancer You can have your opinion, but rest assured I do have a faint idea of what i'm doing. The idea is that under Debug build you get an assert if you have an error. In Release, the function just returns an error. abort is not being called from abort here. It's just the handler hook, which is NOT abort.

Comment: Look at the stack trace for that handler, for me it is `ucrtbased.dll!abort()` and I see no documentation for what happens with that. Using your own macro/routine would give you more control without platform specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `std::abort(-1);` to exit from the function given to `_CrtSetReportHook` seems to make everything work correctly.

This works because googletest spawns another process to execute the test (with EXPECT_DEATH). And it's actually expecting for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly related to the question but it looks like it's a XY problem here.  What really sounds like a code smell is :

> check that any derived class implements a function a certain way

If every derived class has to throw if they are given a nullptr as input parameter, then you might want to have a base class between your interface and the actual implementation classes that does the job once before calling the specific derived class methods.

This is an example of usage of the Non-Virtual interface (NVI) pattern.

In a nutshell 
headers would be

```
Interface::setPtr(void * ptr) = 0 ;

BaseClass::setPtr(void * ptr) final;
BaseClass::setPtr_impl(void * ptr) = 0;

SpecificClass::setPtr_impl(void * ptr);
```

Implementation would be

```
BaseClass::setPtr(void * ptr) {
assert(ptr != nullptr);
setPtr_impl(ptr);
}

SpecificClass::setPtr_impl(void * ptr)
{
//actual code, ptr can not be null
}
```

all this requires that you have no multithreading that could invalidated the ptr.

Comment: Sure enough I could use NVI here. I appreciate thinking outside the constraints. But the thing is that I didn't want to go into too much detail here, nullptr was just a simple example that anyone would understand. +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks for having named the pattern :-) I will update the answer. The more you have to pre-process in the BaseClass, the more it makes sense to implement it.